# Spring Boot findbyid returning Optional error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Hello Friends i am creating an Library Management application with Thymeleaf, i already mapped the relations and created some relations, and the Many to Many ones are working, for example you will register a Book(Only the name), then it will have a link named details where you will be able to complete the register and select the Authors and Themes, both are Many to Many relation and its working

Book Register Details shows one created book
[image]

Now my problem is in the Many to One relationship, it works the same way, you will create a Library, then in Details you will be able to add Books to that library

[image]

[image]

And in the project that i am creating One Library can have multiple Books, but one Book can be in one Library Only, its unique to that library, when i try to add the book and submit i get an Error saying:

No value present
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:141)

And i am trying to solve this for a couple hours, and my guess is that the controller are not able to find the Book id, but i dont have idea why...

Here is my code above:
Ps: i know i have work to do, create the DTOs and make cleaner, i just want to make it work first

Library COntroller here is where i am trying to add the created book in the ediLib method

```
package com.msoftwares.librarymanager.controller;

import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Entities.Book;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Entities.Library;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Repo.LibraryRepository;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Services.BookService;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Services.LibraryService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path ="/api/library")
public class LibraryController {

    @Autowired
    LibraryService libraryService;

    @Autowired
    BookService bookService;




    @GetMapping(path = "/all")
    public ModelAndView getLibraries(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("libraryTemplate");
        modelAndView.addObject("newLibrary", new Library());
        modelAndView.addObject("getLibraries", libraryService.getLibrary());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/details/{id}")
    public ModelAndView getDetails(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){
        Library library = libraryService.findLibById(id);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("libraryEdit");
        modelAndView.addObject("library", library );
        List<Book> unselectedBooks = bookService.getBooks();
        unselectedBooks.removeAll(library.getBook());
        modelAndView.addObject("availableBooks", unselectedBooks);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/editLib")
    public RedirectView editLib(@ModelAttribute Book book, @RequestParam Integer libId){
        Library library = libraryService.findLibById(libId);
        book = bookService.getBookById(book.getIsbn());
        libraryService.saveLibrary(library);


        return new RedirectView("http://localhost:8080/api/library/details/" + libId);
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/create")
    public RedirectView createLibrary(@ModelAttribute Library library){
        libraryService.saveLibrary(library);
        return new RedirectView("http://localhost:8080/api/library/all");
    }


}
```

Book Controller

```
package com.msoftwares.librarymanager.controller;

import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Entities.Author;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Entities.Book;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Entities.BookTheme;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Entities.Library;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Repo.AuthorRepository;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Repo.BookRepository;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Repo.BookThemeRepository;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Repo.LibraryRepository;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Services.AuthorService;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Services.BookService;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Services.BookThemeService;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Services.LibraryService;
import org.dom4j.rule.Mode;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path ="/api/books")
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    BookService bookService;

    @Autowired
    AuthorService authorService;

    @Autowired
    BookThemeService bookThemeService;

    //get all books
    @GetMapping(path = "/all")
    public ModelAndView getBooks(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("booksTemplate");
        modelAndView.addObject("newBook", new Book());
        modelAndView.addObject("getAuthors", authorService.getAuthors());
        modelAndView.addObject("getBooks", bookService.getBooks());
        modelAndView.addObject("getThemes", bookThemeService.getThemes());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    //create book
    @PostMapping(path = "/create")
    public RedirectView createBook(@ModelAttribute Book book) {
        bookService.saveBook(book);
        return new RedirectView("http://localhost:8080/api/books/all");
    }

    //get details
    @GetMapping(path = "/details/{id}")
    public ModelAndView getDetails(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){
        Book book = bookService.getBookById(id);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("bookDetails");
        modelAndView.addObject("bookId", book);
        List<Author> unselectedAuthors = authorService.getAuthors();
        List<BookTheme> unselectedBookThemes = bookThemeService.getThemes();
        unselectedAuthors.removeAll(book.getAuthors());
        unselectedBookThemes.removeAll(book.getBookThemes());
        modelAndView.addObject("authors", unselectedAuthors);
        modelAndView.addObject("bookThemes", unselectedBookThemes);

        return modelAndView;
    }

    //register authors
    @PostMapping(path = "/registerDetails")
    public RedirectView registerDetails(@ModelAttribute Author author, @RequestParam Integer isbn){
        Book book = bookService.getBookById(isbn);
        author = authorService.getAuthorById(author.getId());

        book.getAuthors().add(author);

        bookService.saveBook(book);
        return new RedirectView("http://localhost:8080/api/books/details/" + isbn);
    }

    //register themes
    @PostMapping(path = "/registerTheme")
    public RedirectView registerThemes(@ModelAttribute BookTheme bookTheme, @RequestParam Integer isbn){
        Book book = bookService.getBookById(isbn);
        bookTheme = bookThemeService.getThemeById(bookTheme.getId());

        book.getBookThemes().add(bookTheme);
        bookService.saveBook(book);
        return new RedirectView("http://localhost:8080/api/books/details/" + isbn);
    }



}
```

Library Service

```
package com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Services;

import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Entities.Book;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Entities.Library;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Repo.LibraryRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class LibraryService {

    @Autowired
    LibraryRepository libraryRepository;

    @Autowired
    BookService bookService;


    //get all
    public List<Library> getLibrary(){return libraryRepository.findAll();}

    //get by id
    public Library findLibById(int id){return libraryRepository.findById(id).get();}

    //save
    public void saveLibrary(Library library){libraryRepository.save(library);}

    //delete
    public void deleteLibrary(Library library){libraryRepository.delete(library);}

    

}
```

Book Service (Where the finById method are)

```
package com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Services;

import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Entities.Author;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Entities.Book;
import com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Repo.BookRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class BookService {

    @Autowired
    BookRepository bookRepository;

    //get all books
    public List<Book> getBooks(){
        return bookRepository.findAll();
    }

    //save book
    public void saveBook(Book book){
        bookRepository.save(book);
    }

    //find books by id
    public Book getBookById(int id){
        return bookRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    //delete
    public void deleteBook(Book book){
        bookRepository.delete(book);
    }



}
```

Library Entity

```
package com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Entities;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Library {

    public Library(String name, String address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String address;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany
    private List<Book> book = new ArrayList<>();


}
```

Book Entity

```
package com.msoftwares.librarymanager.models.Entities;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Book {

    public Book(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int isbn;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<BookTheme> bookThemes = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    private Library library;


}
```

I see that the findById method.get it came from an Optional interface where it checks if it have the value or not, but the id is on my DB, he just isnt able to find the id, i try to make the relation on Book Controller and it worked, but in the Library controller it doesnt.

Comment: There are too much informations. You should put comments in the code to guide us.
You say in method `addBook(int isbn, int libId)` , the `bookService.getBookById(isbn);` fails with `Optional Error` ?

Comment: @g.momo i am sorry, the problem is in the Library Controller, in the editLib method, there is where i am trying to add created books to the specific library

Comment: And when i try to add i get the Optional Error, probably because its not finding de id of the book

Comment: By the way, I think before (or instead of) `libraryService.saveLibrary(library);` you should update `book.setLibrary(library);` then  `bookService.saveBook(book);`

Comment: @g.momo you are right, but keep getting the Optional error, it just dont find the book id

Comment: when you print the book.isbn() before calling bookService.findBookId(book.isbn()), what do you see ?

Comment: @g.momo i can get the ISBN in the book controller, the problem is when i am calling from library controller, it seems that it cannot find

Comment: I mean, the @ModelAttribute book. Is it well constructed ? If so, then a printing must show a good value. <br/>  What if you put @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) before each of your service ?

Comment: @g.momo i tried my friend add the transactional, but it didn't work, i am sure that i ve made something wrong, but i must tell you... I dont have a clue!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229225/discussion-between-g-momo-and-leonardo-tadeu-mantovani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After examinating your code, your problem is in your thymeleaf template.

**libraryEdit.html**

```html
<form th:action="@{/api/library/editLib/(libId=${library.id})}" method="post">
        <label><b> Select Books</b></label>
        <select name="id" required>
            <option value="">Choose books</option>
            <option th:each="book : ${availableBooks}"
                    th:value="${book.isbn}"
                    th:text="${book.title}">
            </option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
```

You must change **id** with **isbn**

```html
        <select name="isbn" required>
```

Because your entity Book has **isbn** as Id:

```
public class Book {
    //...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int isbn;

    // ...
```

You had been confused by it because, in the case of bookDetails.html for instance, you use "id" for authors and themes without problem because

```html
 <select name="id" required>
```

Their entities have both

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;
```

To know more about how ModelAttribute works, see this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation#2-as-a-method-argument),

Comment: Thanks friend, for real i guess i got so much worried and upset about this problem, that i couldn't see this error, really thanks my friend!!!

Comment: It was a pleasure to help you.